# How To Queue Work To Be Done By The Server ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, message-queue

We have a CSV uploader where users can upload a CSV file filled with address, city, state, zipcode. The CSV files can be hundreds, thousands, even 10's of thousands of rows.

We need to geocode the rows; no problem, we are using Google Maps RESTFul Web Service, but I don't want to make the user wait while we geocode every row (it can take some time). Basically, I want the upload to complete, and then magically, pass the geocode job off to the server, and allow the user to continue navigating the web app, while the geocodes happen in the background.

I think, this system, requires a queue or job based software; maybe ZeroMQ or RabbitMQ? I have no experience with this, so baby feeding would be amazing. We are using ASP.NET C#.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your idea to use queuing is sound.  WCF with MSMQ endpoints is an alternative to third-party queuing technologies if you're developing for Windows boxes.

Comment: You probably mean WCF, not WFC.

Comment: The first time I even wrote MFC.

Comment: Ah yes, configuring WCF takes a bit of effort.

Answer (score 2):

This should be possible by spinning up a new thread, onto which you pass the geocoding work, then returning the page response to the user as normal. [This question covers much the same problem.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1024908/is-it-possible-to-return-an-asp-page-before-continuing-slow-server-side-work-eg)

You could try something like:

```
ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(delegate {
    DoGeocoding(state details);
});
```

You may or may not need to call Response.Flush after that to return the current page request, and allow the user to carry on browsing.

Comment: Yup, it's c# code just like any other. Each incoming request has it's own thread already. The only risk is that you want to return the visitors page without waiting for the child thread to return, you don't want the parent thread to wait, or the child thread to get killed prematurely. It'd be worth reading a tutorial on threading as I'm not an expert (or good teacher!), but it's not as difficult to learn as some people make out.

Answer (score 1):

An alternative to message queue software would be to use a database to track the CSV processing requests.

Your CSV processing code can update the table as the status of each request changes.

Your ASP.NET site can query the table to display the status of each request to the users.

Comment: But the problem is that the data (ArrayList), is still on the original ASP.NET page which the user called to upload. I want that page to finish loading, so the user can navigate to other pages, unaware, that in the background, we are still geocoding the CSV addresses. I need to somehow pass the ArrayList to a child worker.

Comment: @Justin - When the user uploads, don't immediately kick off the geocoding from the current ASP.NET thread.  Just insert the items into a table, and send a response back to the browser.  In a separate application, periodically look for new items in the table and kick off the geocoding processing.